# Screen reader not reading the Headings when navigating back - React JS

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, nvda

I want to make the headings (H1 tag) to be auto focused on page load so the screen reader can read the headings.

With the below code I made it work as expected.

`<fieldset> <h1 role="alert"> <a id="specialfocusable" tabIndex={-1}> Component A </a> </h1> </fieldset>`

My app is like a stepper, were we move from `component A` to `Component B` similarly `Component B` to `component A`.

Problem is when navigating from `Component B` to `component A` heading text is not read by screen reader.

Please help me to resolve this problem as I'm not finding any solution.

Below is the app link,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ckrut8?file=a.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Simply cleaning up that code should be enough:

```html
<h1 id="h1" tabindex="-1">Component 1</h1>
```

followed by

```js
h1.focus()
```

There is a lot wrong in the posted code, which might cause the issues with the screen reader.

Most importantly it’s changing the H1’s role. Most screen reader users rely on finding headlines for orientation and navigation. There are shortcuts that help jump directly to the H1, for example.

An `alert` is not needed since focus is being moved to the headline. It will get announced on focus.

A [`<fieldset>` is for forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) and would need to have an accessible name. It’s simply invalid here.

### How to React that?

To focus an element you’ll need to access the rendered DOM. Therefore you [use the `ref` property along with `useRef()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref)

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const h1Ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    h1Ref.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return <h1 ref={h1Ref} tabIndex={-1} />;
}
```

Comment: `theH1.focus()` what this means ? could you please explain

Comment: as suggested, I've updated my code to `<h1 id="h1" tabindex="-1">Component 1</h1>` now how do I add the `theH1.focus()`

Comment: Since you’re in react, you’ll need to integrate in the lifecycle and use a `ref` to identify that element in the rendered DOM. Here is a tutorial that looks not bad: https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-set-focus-on-an-input-field-after-rendering-in-react/

Comment: I assumed you already knew because you didn’t ask for how to actually set the focus…

Comment: Ok, I did exactly same, but focus is getting set If I move from component B to component A

Comment: Please checkout my updated stackblitz project file https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hn8ev4?

Comment: I think after all the components are loaded, focus is getting reset again. any way to fix this problem ?